# loop through json file python to get specific key and values

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file built like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"010020000A0225","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.430767,46.0214267],[5.4310805,46.0220116],[5.4311205,46.0220864],[5.4312362,46.0223019],[5.4308994,46.0224141],[5.43087,46.0224242],[5.430774,46.0222401],[5.4304506,46.0223202],[5.4302885,46.021982],[5.4300391,46.0216054],[5.4299637,46.0216342],[5.4300862,46.0218401],[5.4299565,46.021902],[5.4298847,46.0218195],[5.4298545,46.0217829],[5.4297689,46.0216672],[5.4297523,46.0216506],[5.4297379,46.0216389],[5.4296432,46.0215854],[5.429517,46.0214509],[5.4294188,46.0213458],[5.4293757,46.0213128],[5.4291918,46.0211768],[5.4291488,46.0211448],[5.4291083,46.0211214],[5.429024,46.0210828],[5.4292965,46.0208202],[5.4294241,46.0208894],[5.4295183,46.0209623],[5.4295455,46.0209865],[5.429613,46.0210554],[5.4296428,46.0210813],[5.4298751,46.0212862],[5.429988,46.0213782],[5.430014,46.0213973],[5.4300746,46.0214318],[5.430124,46.0214542],[5.4302569,46.0215069],[5.4303111,46.0215192],[5.4303632,46.0215166],[5.4306127,46.0214642],[5.430767,46.0214267]]]},"properties":{"id":"010020000A0225","commune":"01002","prefixe":"000","section":"A","numero":"225","contenance":9440,"arpente":false,"created":"2005-06-03","updated":"2018-09-25"}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"010020000A0346","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.4241952,46.0255535],[5.4233594,46.0262031],[5.4232624,46.0262774],[5.4226259,46.0267733],[5.4227608,46.0268718],[5.4227712,46.0268789],[5.4226123,46.0269855],[5.422565,46.0270182],[5.4223546,46.027145],[5.4222957,46.0271794],[5.4221794,46.0272376],[5.4221383,46.0272585],[5.4221028,46.027152],[5.4220695,46.0270523],[5.4220378,46.026962],[5.4220467,46.0269265],[5.4220524,46.0268709],[5.4220563,46.0268474],[5.4222945,46.0268985],[5.4224161,46.0267746],[5.4224581,46.0267904],[5.4226286,46.02666],[5.4226811,46.02662],[5.4227313,46.0265803],[5.4227813,46.0265406],[5.4228535,46.0264868],[5.4229063,46.0264482],[5.4229741,46.0264001],[5.4234903,46.0260331],[5.4235492,46.0259893],[5.4235787,46.0259663],[5.423645,46.0259126],[5.4237552,46.0258198],[5.4237839,46.0257951],[5.4238321,46.0257547],[5.4239258,46.0256723],[5.4239632,46.0256394],[5.4241164,46.0255075],[5.4241952,46.0255535]]]},"properties":{"id":"010020000A0346","commune":"01002","prefixe":"000","section":"A","numero":"346","contenance":2800,"arpente":false,"created":"2005-06-03","updated":"2018-09-25"}},
```

I would like to get for each feature: properties and geometry but I think I loop badly on my json file. here is my code

```
data = pd.read_json(json_file_path)

for key, v in data.items():
    print(f"{key['features']['geometry']} : {v}",
          f"{key['features']['properties']} : {v}")
```

Comment: There is no need for pandas to this kind of stuff. You can do it using the Python standard library. Is there any particular reason you want to use it e.g. you want to use dataframes? What you show in the question certainly does not require pandas.

Comment: yes i want to work with pandas to use dataframe to add data, clean it or delet some rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you are interested in are located in a list that is itself a value of your main dictionary.
If you want to be able to process these values with pandas, it would be better to build your dataframe directly from them:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads("""{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"010020000A0225","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.430767,46.0214267],[5.4310805,46.0220116],[5.4311205,46.0220864],[5.4312362,46.0223019],[5.4308994,46.0224141],[5.43087,46.0224242],[5.430774,46.0222401],[5.4304506,46.0223202],[5.4302885,46.021982],[5.4300391,46.0216054],[5.4299637,46.0216342],[5.4300862,46.0218401],[5.4299565,46.021902],[5.4298847,46.0218195],[5.4298545,46.0217829],[5.4297689,46.0216672],[5.4297523,46.0216506],[5.4297379,46.0216389],[5.4296432,46.0215854],[5.429517,46.0214509],[5.4294188,46.0213458],[5.4293757,46.0213128],[5.4291918,46.0211768],[5.4291488,46.0211448],[5.4291083,46.0211214],[5.429024,46.0210828],[5.4292965,46.0208202],[5.4294241,46.0208894],[5.4295183,46.0209623],[5.4295455,46.0209865],[5.429613,46.0210554],[5.4296428,46.0210813],[5.4298751,46.0212862],[5.429988,46.0213782],[5.430014,46.0213973],[5.4300746,46.0214318],[5.430124,46.0214542],[5.4302569,46.0215069],[5.4303111,46.0215192],[5.4303632,46.0215166],[5.4306127,46.0214642],[5.430767,46.0214267]]]},"properties":{"id":"010020000A0225","commune":"01002","prefixe":"000","section":"A","numero":"225","contenance":9440,"arpente":false,"created":"2005-06-03","updated":"2018-09-25"}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"010020000A0346","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[5.4241952,46.0255535],[5.4233594,46.0262031],[5.4232624,46.0262774],[5.4226259,46.0267733],[5.4227608,46.0268718],[5.4227712,46.0268789],[5.4226123,46.0269855],[5.422565,46.0270182],[5.4223546,46.027145],[5.4222957,46.0271794],[5.4221794,46.0272376],[5.4221383,46.0272585],[5.4221028,46.027152],[5.4220695,46.0270523],[5.4220378,46.026962],[5.4220467,46.0269265],[5.4220524,46.0268709],[5.4220563,46.0268474],[5.4222945,46.0268985],[5.4224161,46.0267746],[5.4224581,46.0267904],[5.4226286,46.02666],[5.4226811,46.02662],[5.4227313,46.0265803],[5.4227813,46.0265406],[5.4228535,46.0264868],[5.4229063,46.0264482],[5.4229741,46.0264001],[5.4234903,46.0260331],[5.4235492,46.0259893],[5.4235787,46.0259663],[5.423645,46.0259126],[5.4237552,46.0258198],[5.4237839,46.0257951],[5.4238321,46.0257547],[5.4239258,46.0256723],[5.4239632,46.0256394],[5.4241164,46.0255075],[5.4241952,46.0255535]]]},"properties":{"id":"010020000A0346","commune":"01002","prefixe":"000","section":"A","numero":"346","contenance":2800,"arpente":false,"created":"2005-06-03","updated":"2018-09-25"}}
]
}
""")

df = pd.DataFrame(data['features'])
print(df)
```

It'll give you the following DataFrame:

```
      type              id                                           geometry                                         properties
0  Feature  010020000A0225  {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[5.430767...  {'id': '010020000A0225', 'commune': '01002', '...
1  Feature  010020000A0346  {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[5.424195...  {'id': '010020000A0346', 'commune': '01002', '...
```

From there you can easily access the `geometry` and `properties` columns.

Furthermore, if you want geometric and other properties in their own columns, you can use `json_normalize`:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['features'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      type              id geometry.type                               geometry.coordinates  ... properties.contenance properties.arpente properties.created properties.updated
0  Feature  010020000A0225       Polygon  [[[5.430767, 46.0214267], [5.4310805, 46.02201...  ...                  9440              False         2005-06-03         2018-09-25
1  Feature  010020000A0346       Polygon  [[[5.4241952, 46.0255535], [5.4233594, 46.0262...  ...                  2800              False         2005-06-03         2018-09-25
```